# python 3.5 returns memory address instead of value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function to return the sum of two vectors. However, my function returns the memory instead of value.

```
def vector_add2(vector1, vector2):
    return map(lambda x,y: x+y, vector1, vector2)
```

I also wrote another function to compute the dot product.

```
def dot_product2(vector1, vector2):
    return sum(map(lambda x, y: x*y, vector1, vector2))
```

This function works well. Is the map function problem?

Comment: the `sum` function will "consume" the `map` object that is created and return a value.

Comment: It doesn't return a memory address, it returns a `map` object (which has inherited it's `repr` from `object`, so it includes the memory address), which is evaluated *lazily* in Python 3 as opposed to eagerly in Python 2

Comment: well, I solved the problem. What I did is to create a list using the map object: return list(sum...)